# While executing action (with delegate and protocol included), a part does't work

Tags: swift

I have a custom cell class called "customerInformationTableViewCell". I have a textfield in this cell. I created an action which is on when the editing finishes. I have created a protocol and delegate to share information with my view controller. But the code after the guard (included) doesn't seem working as the print("2") doesn't work. What's the issue ? Please help !

```
@IBAction func textField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("1")
        guard let cell = sender.superview as? customerInformationTableViewCell else { return }
        print("2")
        let indexPath = (sender.superview?.superview as! UITableView).indexPath(for: cell)
        self.delegate?.shareDetailsInvoice(row: indexPath!.row, input: textField.text!)
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint there, check what the value of `sender.superview` actually is. Presumably either it's nil or it isn't a `customerInformationTableViewCell`.

Comment: On a side note, standard practice is to start type names with a capital letter to better distinguish them from variable names, so that should be "CustomerInformationTableViewCell."

Comment: Thanks and I will note your remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one workaround is to use this extension

```
import UIKit
  extension UIView {
    func lookForSuperviewOfType<T: UIView>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        guard let view = self.superview as? T else {
            return self.superview?.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: type)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

How to use it

```
let cell = sender.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: customerInformationTableViewCell.self)
```

And to get TableView

```
let tableView = sender.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: UITableView.self)
```

So your function will become like this

```
 @IBAction func textField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("1")
        guard let cell = sender.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: customerInformationTableViewCell.self)  else { return }
        print("2")
        let indexPath = sender.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: UITableView.self)?.indexPath(for: cell)
        self.delegate?.shareDetailsInvoice(row: indexPath!.row, input: textField.text!)
    }
```